# How to get IP laravel 5.1 and print?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, ip

I am working on Laravel 5.1 and do not know how to get the IP and print it. I know that in PHP using `$_SERVER[“REMOTE_ADDR”]`.

I have tried this `{!!Request::ip()!!}` but nothing. Please help me

Comment: Please describe your error, normally it should work. Where do you use this?

Comment: i am working in localhost:8080 and when i use {!!Request::ip()!!}  in the html  and i see this ::1 in the area i put this

Comment: Well that's correct :D

Comment: what can be de problem? the code is like this:      <a class="navbar-brand" >{!!Request::ip()!!}</a>  it is ok?

Comment: There is no problem mate, it will work on a live server just fine ;)

Comment: well i have to try this in a server thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's fine, ::1 is localhost on IPv6, Try 127.0.0.1:8000 to fix your issue if you want IPv4